Can I use apriori / association rules on aggregate data?
I'm trying to find patterns for cross selling opportunities for a professional services company. I'm using apriori to do this.
My company has different project types. We might work for a client on one or several project types at the same time. Over time, these project types could change.
We usually bill our clients monthly. A client could receive several bills. By design, all the invoices have only 1 project type per invoice, so if we're working on more than one project type (which may or may not be related), they could receive several bills in a single month.
I took bills for the last 10 years (each bill had just one project type assigned), and ran apriori for each client.  When I included the bill number, I didn't find any consequents. When I removed it so that the client's entire project type history was evaluated at once, I got a lot of strong matches. I'm wondering whether it's appropriate to manipulate the process this way. All of the tutorials I see use the bill number.
